# google cloud not releasing connections

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We migrated our mysql db to google cloud and before the migration, open connection to the db was constant at 30. However in cloud, it goes up and down average 200.
Is there any know issue with google cloud causing connections not being released?

Comment: Can you give some more details on your setup? Are you connection from Google Compute Engine? Google Compute Engine? From what language? Are you using some framework that manages the MySQL connections? What does a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show?

Comment: We are running the cluster of apps from onpremise and it is using mysql jdbc driver with java 7.  "show processlist" results were fluctuation for no reason. Each service opens up 5 connections and keeps them however processlist was returning crazy number of connections like 60 then 200, kept fluctuation...

Comment: I would recommend identifying the extra connections and understand the code that is creating them.

Answer (score 0):

connect_timeout and max_connections of Cloud SQL instances have different default values compare to standard MySQL installation. You need to look at your codes to see how connect_timeout impact the number of connections of your application:

variable                         Cloud SQL         MySQL 
`------------------------------------------`
connect_timeout              60                       10 
max_connections           250                151